# Can ros use the unstable branch of openni for OS X?

Tags: ros, openni, libusb, macos-snowleopard, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My on-going attempt to get openni running on Snow Leopard ....

Update:

- OpenNI fails as described in my other question.
- libusb-devel won't install either (though I have loaded the binaries...for another question)
- The OpenNI project has an unstable branch that will install on my system. (See
  [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/openni-dev/browse_thread/thread/c8843abd566f7869/f4a61c615f396214?lnk=gst&q=nite+64bit#f4a61c615f396214).)

So is it possible to have the openni install [as described in the wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ni) use this unstable branch? Or does that not make sense?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9306/can-ros-use-the-unstable-branch-of-openni-for-os-x?/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We generally prefer to wait for unstable branches to be tested by the upstream developers before releasing them to our users as the default option.  It is a matter of balancing stability versus new features.

If the new features are a blocker for you(which it seems to be), I suggest that you create a branch of the stack and switch to use the openni unstable branch.  As an early adopter you get the privilege of being one of the people who reports bugs so that when it is deployed as the default option there are less.

If you do this other OSX user would appreciate if you would document how to check out your patched version with OSX support on the wiki.   Once OSX support is merged into the default release we can clean up the special OSX instructions.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-03-06**:
I appreciate your confidence, though I fear it is unwarranted!  I may take a crack at this, if you can point me to instructions on incorporating the unstable openni branch into the stack?